# Shrink paragraph after word wrap

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a problem with breaking word in a paragraph in a toast message.
[image: Toast message]

Whole toast message has min and max width. "User does... Coffe_VisionBoards_2014a_V2.mp4" is one paragraph. This paragraph has word-wrap set to break-word. It works fine, but I want it to shrink after applying word-wrap.

The final result should be something like this:

[image: Shrinked Toast message]

If I set paragraph width to 100px, it will shrink whole toast message. So the problem is that the paragraph is not shrinking after wrapping.

**EDIT:**

Link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMvzKG

**html:**

```
<md-toast>
          <div class="toast" flex layout="column" layout-align="center start">
            <h3 class="break-word">Header</h3>
            <p class="break-word">User does not have permission to open: Coffe_VisionBoards_2014A_V2.mp4</p>
        </div>
</md-toast>
```

**CSS:**

```
.toast{
  min-width:100px;
  max-width:400px;
}

.break-word{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Is there any way how to achieve it?
Thank you

Comment: Please share example

Comment: please include your relevant code (html and css)

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve this using HTML & CSS.